# Passing component tag in data

Tags: vue.js, templates, vuejs2

Is it possible to call component tag `modalBlock` as data?

```
<template>
<div v-html="modalBlock">
</div>
</template>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            modalBlock: `<general-modal
                            is-gray-bg="true">
                            <template v-slot:header>
                                <h3 v-text="modalHeader"></h3>
                            </template>

                            <template v-slot:body
                                      v-if="isModalOpened">

                                <div v-if="fetchedGift">
                                    <gift
                                        :gift="JSON.stringify(fetchedGift)"
                                    ></gift>
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>
                                        <div>
                                            <gift-list></gift-list>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </template>

                            <template v-slot:txt>
                                <a class="link-blue">Choose</a>
                            </template>
                        </general-modal>`,
            modalHeader: 'Choose gift',
            isModalOpened: false,
            fetchedGift: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a `<component />` element and set the `:is` attribute to a an options object that uses your modal block template.  you will need to import the version of vue that has the runtime compiler.

Comment: instead of having it stored in the data..you can have a seperate component created and
then use it here by

<component v-bind:is="component_name"></component>